# Howto select only rows from Table 1 which have same values in Table 2 (C# - Entity Framework to Entities

Tags: linq-to-entities

i`m new in Linq and have a question.

I have Table 1 with some values in Columns named Aktie and Depot (and much more). Than i have a Table 2 with also Columns named Aktie and Depot (and much more).

My result should be that all rows from table 1 select first and than i need only the rows from Table 1 which correspondent the same combination of Aktie and Depot column in Table 2

That`s what i tried till now:

```
var query =
        from u in _context.Table1.ToList().GroupBy(m => 
new { m.Aktie, m.Depotname }).Select(x => x.First()).OrderBy(x => x.Aktie)
        join l in _context.Table2 on u.Aktie equals l.Aktie
        where u.Depotname == l.DepotName
        select u;
```

Can someone help me ? The results are not correct.....

Comment: in other words - ALL entries from Table2 with same combination of Aktie and Depot column values which are also in Table1 should be the result....hope it is clear what i want ?

Comment: in Table 2 it is possible that there are more than one row which is corresponding Aktie and Depot column, than this row should only select once....

Comment: Your result can't be both "all rows from table 1" and "only rows from Table 1" - can you rephrase your question to be clear?

Comment: Yes of cours - sorry for my bad englisch.

Comment: In Table 1 are 77 rows, in Table 2 only 47 rows. I need the select on Table1 with all rows from Table 2 depending on column "Aktie" and "Depot". The result should show 47 rows.  I will try to append a picture which a sample

Comment: You shouldn't add an Answer or comment with more information about your question, you can easily edit your original question.

Comment: Your picture shows that all of Table1 is returned, so if Table1 has 77 rows all of which have matching values in Table2, then all 77 rows should be returned.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming what you mean to ask is how to select all rows from Table1 where exists at least one row in Table2 that has the same value for columns Aktie and Depot, here is how to do this in LINQ - some of these methods may not work with LINQ to SQL/Entities. Each answer is provided in query and lambda/method/fluent syntax.

```
// using join
var ans = from u in _context.Table1
          join l in _context.Table2 on new { u.Aktie, u.Depotname } equals new { l.Aktie, Depotname = l.DepotName }
          select u;

var ans2 = _context.Table1.Join(_context.Table2, u => new { u.Aktie, u.Depotname }, l => new { l.Aktie, Depotname = l.DepotName }, (u, l) => u);

// using Any
var ans3 = from u in _context.Table1
           where (from l in _context.Table2 where u.Aktie == l.Aktie && u.Depotname == l.DepotName select l).Any()
           select u;

var ans4 = _context.Table1.Where(u => _context.Table2.Any(l => u.Aktie == l.Aktie && u.Depotname == l.DepotName));

// using Contains
var ans5 = from u in _context.Table1
           where (from l in _context.Table2 select new { l.Aktie, Depotname = l.DepotName }).Contains(new { u.Aktie, u.Depotname })
           select u;

var ans6 = _context.Table1.Where(u => _context.Table2.Select(l => new { l.Aktie, Depotname = l.DepotName }).Contains(new { u.Aktie, u.Depotname }));
```

Comment: Hi Netmage,first of all - thanks a lot for your great help !
The amount of yours is ever 77 - but should be 47.

Comment: As i showed in my picture it is possible that there are many rows with same Aktie and Depot value. But the result should contain only one row. It should be a copy of table 2 (47 items) but with all values of Table 1.....

Possibly you have an idea how to fix this ?

At the moment i do this to reach the same result - but i want to learn it via Linq:

Comment: `foreach (var item in Table1)
            {
                foreach (var item2 in Table2)
                {
                    if(item.Aktie == item2.Aktie && item.Depotname == item2.DepotName)
                    {
                        DatenFuerSelect.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }`

Comment: @fahr LINQ to SQL works correctly with it, I'd think you'd have to debug the SQL translation to see what is going on, which can depend on what EF you are using.

Comment: If you only want one copy of each matching Table1 row, how do you want to select which row to return?